# How does one achieve a 'shimmering' effect similiar to the ones from the Pokemon games?

Tags: c++, graphic-effects, winapi

I have an assignment to make a game in C++ using Winapi. As such I've decided to recreate pieces of the Pokemon games. I'm pretty well underway with the project, but there's one effect I would like to achieve that I don't really know how to achieve.

It can first be seen just before the game's title screen. (Pictured below)

[image]
As you can see, the logo sort of 'shimmers' from left to right a few times.

A similiar effect can be seen inside of combat when a pokemon's stats are altered. (Pictured below)

[image]
The effects I am talking about are the reddish shimmer appearing on the wolf (Poochyena), and the blue 'waves' appearing on the beaver (Bibarel).

I would like to know if there is a generalized method of applying such effects, as I aspire to have more than one Pokemon in the project, and I would therefore want a method that works on all cases. If the effect cannot be effectively achieved using winapi, then I am open to suggestions of other libraries, etc, to use.

Comment: Looks like blending two textures together to me, not really "effect". At least the second case.

Comment: @wondra That sounds like what I'm looking for, is such a thing possible using winapi or will I need something more advanced?

Comment: @Bálint I'd agree with regard to the logo animation, but the status effect animations would be harder to execute in the way described at that link. I'd recommend leaving this question open to get answers about this type of overlaid texture scrolling effect, which can achieve both examples.